# how to make child div to "do not inherit background color" from its father div?

Tags: css, inheritance

I want make different background between father elem and child elem.

fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/cbcL6osm/

I mean, if you see the child div, its background color is red inherited from father div.

That's not I want.

I want make child div to only shows its background image, and do not inherit background color from its father div.

Below is the code of fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/cbcL6osm/

```
html :
<div class="father">
    test
    <div class="child">
        test
    </div>
</div>


css :
.father {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color:red;
    position:relative;
}

.child {
    position:absolute;
    top:20px;
    left:20px;
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    background:url('https://www.google.co.kr/logos/doodles/2014/leo-tolstoys-186th-birthday-5756677508825088.2-res.png') center;
    background-size:30px 30px;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    border:thin solid;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The point, actually, is your false premise.

**The child div does not inherit the parent's background color**

The default background of the div is transparent, that is why the red color is appearing. You would need to replace the `background-color` of the child div with another one.

[**MDN background-color docs**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-color) states:

> **Initial value:** transparent
>   **Inherited:** no

Comment: Exactly, there is no "inherit" going on. Default is transparent that's why you see it Red. The above answer with the `box-shadow: 0 0 0 5em red;` is a trick not THE answer