# Background colour getting implemented to both target element and its child elements using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, events, event-handling

I have a hierarchy of HTML elements and I want that when a left mouse click happen in an element in this hierarchy, the background colour of only that specific element should get changed. I want to use a different background colour for each of these elements. I have multiple CSS classes to change the background colour.
I am trying to add these css classes dynamically to these HTML elements using JavaScript event handling.

When I am executing this code and performing a Left Mouse click on the element with id "outer-container", the dark-green background colour is getting implemented to not only this element with id "outer-container", but also to its child elements. Similarly if I left-click on element with id "inner-container", its red-background colour is getting implemented to it as well as to its children elements. Whereas I want that the background colour should get applied only to the element which received the left-click event, neither to any of its children nor to any of its parents.

I have tried using event.stopPropagation to stop bubbling / capturing events. But the problem still persists. Please suggest what am I doing wrong here and how can I achieve what I am intending to?

```js
const outerContainer = document.getElementById("outer-container");
const innerContainer = document.getElementById("inner-container");
const innerButton1Container = document.getElementById("inner-button-1-container");
const innerButton1 = document.getElementById("inner-button1");
const innerButton2Container = document.getElementById("inner-button2-container");
const innerButton2 = document.getElementById("inner-button2");

const mouseDownHandler = (targetElement, classToAdd) => {
  console.log(`Left Press Down happened in ${targetElement.id}.`);
  targetElement.classList.add(classToAdd, "white-font");
}

outerContainer.addEventListener('mousedown', (event) => {
  let classToAdd = "dark-green-background";
  mouseDownHandler(event.target, classToAdd);
  event.stopPropagation();
}, false);

innerContainer.addEventListener('mousedown', (event) => {
  let classToAdd = "dark-red-background";
  mouseDownHandler(event.target, classToAdd);
  event.stopPropagation();
}, false);
```

```css
.dark-green-background {
  background-color: #006614;
}
.dark-red-background {
  background-color: #9b0303;
}
/* and many more colors */

.white-font {
  color: white;
}
div {
  padding-left: 1em;
}
```

```html
  <div id="outer-container" class="container">
    This text is in the outer container.
    <div id="inner-container" class="container">
      This text is in the inner container.
      <div id="inner-button1-container" class="container">
        This is inner button 1 container.
        <button id="inner-button1" class="button">Inner Button 1</button>
      </div>
      <div id="inner-button2-container" class="container">
        This is inner button 2 container.
        <button id="inner-button2" class="button">Inner Button 2</button>
      </div>
      This text is just before the inner container is ending.
    </div>
    This text is again in the outer container.
  </div>
```

Comment: Related - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25747982/how-to-make-child-div-to-do-not-inherit-background-color-from-its-father-div

Comment: You say "*I want to use a different background colour for each of these elements*", but you are not assigning the individual elements any background color? They're all transparent by default!

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @James and @Bergi, I was missing out on the fact that the default background of the div is transparent. I Added `background-color: white;` and `color: black;` to the "container" class properties, and it resolved the visibility issue with child elements.

Comment: @mplungjan I think it's a well-written question, and it is generic enough to be useful to others (not just a typo). Triviality is not a reason for deletion

Comment: The question was well written (and I made the code into a [mcve]) but the solution was trivial in my eyes. But fine, I'll leave it up to OP